# Is a residency permit for non-EU nationals a valid travel document in Portugal?

Tags: residency

Is a temporary residency card issued by Portugal enough to satisfy the "Passport or any other valid travel document" requirement listed here?

https://imigrante.sef.pt/en/renovar-residencia/art78-2-rg/

Comment: There are no EU rules on this. There are countries where such a document is accepted for many purposes and others where it's only useful together with a passport. I edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

No, since the residence permit card (called **Residence Title**) itsself is also required in that list:

> [Article 78, paragraph 2 – Renewing a Residence Permit (General regime) – The Official Website of Portuguese Immigration](https://imigrante.sef.pt/en/renovar-residencia/art78-2-rg/)
> ...
>
> - Two recent, identical photographs, in colour with blank background, and easily identifiable (only for appointments at Odivelas, Aveiro or Braga SEF bureau)
> - **Residence Title** valid, or expired in the previous 6 months
> - Passport or any other valid travel document
>
> ...

Comment: I don't follow your logic

Comment: @user124063 the logic is this: the list says that you need the document that you have (call that "document A") and that you also need a "passport or other travel document" (call that "document B"). If document A also satisfied the requirement for document B, then there would be no need to state a requirement for document B.  The reason they say "or other travel document" is to allow for those who might have a refugee travel document or a stateless person's travel document instead of a passport.

Comment: @phoog How would a stateless person get a travel document in this case? From the country he's a resident of, which is Portugal, right? What would be the name of this document? You're saying it must be something other than a residence permit so it must be something else

Comment: Or in Portugese, Título de Viagem para Refugiados/para Apátridas.

Comment: @user124063 Technically that would be a ”1954 Convention travel document” but people would probably simply call it a travel document and the cover might say something slightly different. But the logic used in Mark's answer and phoog's comment applies in any case: Even if I didn't know what this document was, I would know it must be distinct from residence permits because it's listed separately.

Comment: @user124063 I wouldn't rule out the possibility that a person who is a permanent resident of some other country might live in Portugal for a few years and therefore need to renew a Portuguese residence permit while holding a stateless or refugee travel document from the other country.  If the travel document is issued by Portugal, though, it would be [one of the documents listed in PRADO in the category "travel document issued to non-nationals](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-documents/PRT/J/docs-per-category.html).

Comment: @user124063 (also, "travel document" is routinely used in the EU/EEA to refer to EU/EEA national ID cards, but a person with such a document would not need a residence permit in Portugal.)

Comment: @phoog if I understand you correctly, a stateless and/or passport-less resident of Portugal can get PRT-JO-02001 listed in the page you linked. Is that correct? So if this person wants to renew his residence permit, he could provide PRT-JO-02001 instead of a passport of another country. But there's something that doesn't make sense. Here https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/PRT-JO-02001/image-292578.html I can see a passport number in the image. I don't know how someone can have a passport ID without having a citizenship.

Comment: @user124063 Because it is a *Travel document issued to foreign nationals **or** stateless persons.*. A refugee will receive such a passport when their country refuses to issue one.

Comment: @user124063 that number is the number of the document you're looking at, not of some other passport.  Note that the document is called the "Passaporte para Estrangeiros," meaning "passport for foreigners."  It is therefore not at all surprising that the document number is labeled "passport number."  It is a document that Portugal chooses to name as a variety of "passport," even though many countries do not use the word "passport" to denote the same sort of document.

Comment: The discussions has strayed away a little from what I thought was the main question. But I suspect also that stateless persons and refugees under Portugese protection may be subject to another regime of renewing their residence documents and certain required elements may be modified.